# -bash: node: command not found (on EC2 instance)

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-ec2

I've encountered problem that I can't use node command.

I've created an instance of EC2(AMI: Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type)

And then I installed packages...

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-213 ~]$sudo yum -y install git gcc-c++ make openssl-devel nginx

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-213 ~]$git clone git://github.com/creationix/nvm.git .nvm

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-213 ~]$source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-213 ~]$nvm install v6.10.3

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-213 ~]$node -v
v6.10.3
```

And then, I build a node.js web system.
I was able to access the system.

But,After having a break(for about 2 hour),
Node command became not working...

```
$ [ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-213 ~]$ node -v
-bash: node: command not found
```

Please tell me what is the cause of it.

Comment: what does nvm say? is nvm current still pointing to v6.10.3 ? or is it also somehow resetet?

Comment: Have you tried `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` again?

Comment: @ShabbY,Thank you for your quick response.I can't use nvm command too.

Comment: Did you log out and log back in after your 2-hour break? That would be a new shell instance in which you need to source `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` again, as Z. Bagley points out.

Comment: @Z.Bagley,I'm so sorry,I've solved by the command...

Comment: @chepner,Thank you.and so sorry...I've solved by the command....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by below command.

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Thank you all for your kind response.